# jQuery "for" loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some very basic jQuery code here.

What I am doing here is I want the image to toggle when hover. I have 5 images, and I was able to archive that when I wrote 5 codes, 1 for each image.

```
        $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(1)').hover(function(){
            $('li:nth-child(1) > .image-hover').toggle();
            $('li:nth-child(1) > .image').toggle();
        });

        $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(2)').hover(function(){
            $('li:nth-child(2) > .image-hover').toggle();
            $('li:nth-child(2) > .image').toggle();
        });

        $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(3)').hover(function(){
            $('li:nth-child(3) > .image-hover').toggle();
            $('li:nth-child(3) > .image').toggle();
        });

        $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(4)').hover(function(){
            $('li:nth-child(4) > .image-hover').toggle();
            $('li:nth-child(4) > .image').toggle();
        });

        $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(5)').hover(function(){
            $('li:nth-child(5) > .image-hover').toggle();
            $('li:nth-child(5) > .image').toggle();
        });
```

Now I want to shorten the code, using the "for" loop. The idea is I have a variable i, starting from 1, increasing 1 by 1 up to 5. The nth-child above, instead of having a specific number, will now hold i. As i changes, nth-child(i) will have respective values of i.

```
        (function($){
            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(i)').hover(function(){
                    $('li:nth-child(i) > .image-hover').toggle();
                    $('li:nth-child(i) > .image').toggle();
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

This shorten code doesn't work though.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to use `i` as a variable... still you have the problem described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to target the elements within the currently hovered element, then you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)/[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) in context with `this`(in the event handler `this` refers to the element which was targeted by the handler - in this case the `li` element) like

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#menu > ul:first-child > li').hover(function () {
        //I think you want to target the child elements of the current li so
        $(this).children('.image-hover').toggle();
        $(this).children('.image').toggle();
    });
});
```

Another option since you didn't share the target markup is to find the index of the current `li` using [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and use it to target the `li` in the same index like

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#menu > ul:first-child > li').hover(function () {
        //find the index of the current element
        var i = $(this).index();
        //use i as a variable to find i'th child of li
        $('li:nth-child(' + i + ') > .image-hover').toggle();
        $('li:nth-child(' + i + ') > .image').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. Would you mind explaining your code?

Comment: @user3678075 which one

Comment: @ArunPJohny master updated your ans with little more comment..hope you dont mind doing me so..as always +1 for great ans

Comment: @ArunPJohny The first one, why $(this).children('.image-hover').toggle() ?

Comment: @user3678075 as I said `this` refers the `li` which was hovered so `$(this).children('.image-hover')` will give the `.image-hover` element which is inside the current `li`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: so on start-up, the page will show default images, only when 1 <li> image is hovered then that <script> is called; $(this) refers to the hovered <li> image. Other images are left intact. Am I right?

Comment: @user3678075 no the script is called on load of the script file... but the function passed to `hover()` is called when you hover over the `li`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thank you. I got it. I have 2 sample pages here, can you check this for me.
http://thunguyen.freeiz.com/menu-nav.html
This is the menu nav page, which is included in a bigger page
http://thunguyen.freeiz.com/new-test.html

The small menu page works as expected, the test page does not. There seems to be some error with the image.toggle(). Why is that so?

Comment: @user3678075 in the `new-test.html` page you are not using `hover`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Oh I see. The menu-nav.html is self-contained. I need not write anything that touches the <menu nav> element. I deleted the <menu-nav script>. It now works fine. Thanks a alot Arun.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Oh no. Error again. I have tried both way, with and without the new <script>. The image.toggle() still shows error though.

Comment: can you move the new script to the old script tag instead of creating a new one

Comment: @ArunPJohny: does that mean on the "menu-nav.html" page I delete the <script>, doesn't this make the page incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

This seems can be completely replaced by changing the css hover - background style instead of using javascript to toggle hover image.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your selctor:

> $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(**i**)') to
>   
> $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child(**'+i+'**))'

```
(function($){
            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                $('#menu > ul:first-child > li:nth-child('+i+')').hover(function(){
                    $('li:nth-child('+i+') > .image-hover').toggle();
                    $('li:nth-child('+i+') > .image').toggle();
                });
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

The problem is that your code is taking your i AS i (alphabet) not i AS i(variable) because your i is in quotes remove quotesfrom around i.

Comment: I changed all (i) to ('+i+') but still that doesn't work though.

Comment: Can you please view your full code, or show me a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code.